# C++: calling inherited virtual method using derived class pointer (pointing to derived class object) is resulting in compilation error

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, vtable, dynamic-binding, dynamic-dispatch

Following code results in compilation error.

> error: no matching function for call to ‘D::print(int)’

Error is at following line

> d_ptr->print(5);

```
#include<iostream>
  
using std::cout;

class B {
public:
    virtual void print() {
        cout << "B::print()\n";
    }
    virtual void print(int i) {
        cout << "B::print(int)\n";
    }
};

class D: public B {
public:
    void print() {
        cout << "D::print()\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    D d, *d_ptr = &d;
    B *b_ptr = &d;

    b_ptr->print(5);
    d_ptr->print(5);

    return 0;
}
```

If I comment out the line generating an error then code is working as expected.
So my questions is why `b_ptr->print(5);` is working without compilation error but `d_ptr->print(5);` leads to compilation error?

If `B::print(int)` was non-virtual function then it makes sense. Because in that case `B::print(int)` will hide behind `D::print()`.

But for virtual function, dispach happens at runtime based on virtual-function-table created for the class of the object. Then why it behaves differently when we call `print()` with `d_ptr` instead of `b_ptr`.

I would appreciate if someone can point me to the right resource which can clear my confusion.

Comment: The interface of `D` only has one `print` function. The rules about names and hiding don't care about virtualness.

Comment: In `D` you can add `using B::print;` to pull in all missing overloads from the base.